# How to keep the measure reference line fix?

Tags: measurement

Making confuse with the reference line with the measure tool. Until the measure tool is active the measurement and reference line is seen. When selecting on selection tool to extrude more or less the reference line disappears. How to fix the reference or guideline permanently. Any suggestion or addon? Thanks

[video](https://imgur.com/a/UVaeB1D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have missed something, but so far, I haven't found the measurement tool very useful for construction. As you say, it disappears when you would want it for that, and you don't seem to be able to snap to rulers.

Personally, for precision, where 'carpentry' methods (taking measurements and angles from existing parts)  are not available, I've always worked with pre-prepared, first-class-object, jigs. If you enable the shipped 'MeasureIt' add-on, you can label them, too. Here's one made from 2 edges:

[image]